# VBA code not working for delete ppt slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to delete ppt slides using specific keywords.my code is given below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim PP As Presentation
    Dim ppMaster
    Dim sText As Variant
    strFolderName = "D:\Shaon_Paul\pptss"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx*")
    sText = InputBox("Give me some input")


    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)
        Dim oSld As Slide
        Dim oShp As Shape
        Dim L As Long
        For L = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(L)
             For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
             On Error Resume Next
                If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                    If UBound(Split(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, sText)) > 0 Then
                    PP.Slides(L).Delete
                    End If
                End If
             Next oShp
        Next L

        Set ppMaster = PP.SlideMaster
        With ppMaster
            If UBound(Split(.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text, sText)) > 0 Or UBound(Split(.HeadersFooters.Header.Text, sText)) > 0 Then
                PP.Slides(L).Delete
            End If
        End With

        PP.Save
        PP.Close
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now this code will open a input box where I have to give my keywords and It will delete the slides in a ppt available in the folder where I have mentioned the path name.
Unfortunately while debugging the code

```
If UBound(Split(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, sText)) > 0 Then
                    PP.Slides(L).Delete
                    End If
```

it will jump without executing this code above and unable to delete the slide by giving specific keyword name. Need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the result of UBound(Split(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, sText)) ? What are the values of oShp.TextFrame.TextRange and sText?

Comment: @JeffUK The values for oShp.TextFrame.TextRange ="SLIDER" and for sText I am getting the value for my input keyword.